# VueJS: background img gets uploaded in all sibling components instead of the component through which image was uploaded

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

In this [codeSandBox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/file-blob-repeated-on-parent-why-dzght), the child cmp contains the image file input,

The file is uploaded to and read using `reader.readAsDataURL(file)` as the background image of the input's parent wrapper div.

The problem is that the uploaded file gets repeated in all siblings.

I want to uploaded file to affect only the component where the child was upload.

**Parent.vue**

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div v-for="n in 5">
      <div class="wrapper" :style="bgImg">
        <child @imageSelected="updateBgImg($event)"/>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import child from "./components/child";

  export default {
    name: "App",
    data() {
      return {
        bgImgURL: "Image URL",
        bgImg: {}
      };
    },
    methods: {
      updateBg(url) {
        this.bgImgURL = url;
        this.bgImg = {
          "background-image": "url(" + this.bgImgURL + ")"
        }
      }
    },
    components: {
      child
    }
  }
</script>
```

**child.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <input type="file" @change="getImage">
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",
  props: {
    msg: String
  },
  methods: {
    getImage(e) {
      var file = e.target.files[0];
      this.createImage(file);
    },
    createImage(file) {
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);

      var vm = this;
      reader.onload = function() {
        vm.$emit("imageSelected", this.result);
      };
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Thanks

Comment: Because all five of ` <div class="wrapper" :style="bgImg">` elements are in the parent not in the child so of course `bgImg`  is going to be the same.  Try moving your wrapper into your child and apply the `bgImg` there then each instance will be isolated.

Answer (score 0):

Update the image in your child. Example [on codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/file-blob-repeated-on-parent-why-g93zx)

***Your parent look like this***

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div v-for="n in 5" :key='n'>
        <child/>

        <!-- <child @imageSelected="updateBg($event)"/> -->
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import child from "./components/child";

export default {
  name: "App",
  data() {
    return {
      msg: "Parent Message",
      // testUrl: "Image URL",
      // bgImg: {}
    };
  },
  methods: {
    // updateBg(url,index) {
    //   // this.testUrl = url;
    //   this.bgImg[index] = {
    //     "background-image": "url(" + url + ")"
    //   };
    //   // console.log(this.bgImg);
    // },

  },
  components: {
    child
  }
};
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: "Avenir", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
.wrapper {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-size: cover;
}
</style>
```

***and your child like this***

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="wrapper" :style="img">
      <input type="file" @change="getImage">
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",
  props: {
    msg: String
  },
  data(){
    return {
      img:''
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getImage(e) {
      var file = e.target.files[0];
      this.createImage(file);
    },
    createImage(file) {
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);

      var vm = this;
      reader.onload = function() {
        // console.log(this.result)
        vm.img = {
        "background-image": "url(" + this.result + ")"
      }
        // don't need
        // vm.$emit("imageSelected", this.result);
      };
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

***Updated***

Update image in parent from child. Example [on codepen](https://codesandbox.io/s/file-blob-repeated-on-parent-why-chs5v)

**Your parent**

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div v-for="n in imgCount" :key="n">
      <div class="wrapper" :style="imgs[n]">
        <sibling/>
        <child :image-id="n" @imageSelected="updateBg($event)"/>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import child from "./components/child";
import sibling from "./components/simpleCmp";

export default {
  name: "App",
  data() {
    return {
      imgCount: 5,
      msg: "Parent Message",
      testUrl: "Image URL",
      bgImg: {},
      imgs: []
    };
  },
  methods: {
    updateBg(item) {
      // console.log(item.index);
      this.$set(this.imgs, item.index, item.bg)
    }
  },
  components: {
    child,
    sibling
  }
};
</script>
```

**your child**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <input type="file" @change="getImage">
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",
  props: {
    msg: String,
    imageId: Number
  },
  methods: {
    getImage(e) {
      var file = e.target.files[0];
      if (!file) return;
      this.createImage(file);
    },
    createImage(file) {
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);

      var vm = this;
      reader.onload = function() {
        // console.log(this.result);
        vm.$emit("imageSelected", {
          index: vm.imageId,
          bg: {
            "background-image": "url(" + this.result + ")"
          }
        });
      };
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: The demo I posted is simplified version of my app. In the actual app, there are other sibling component as well to this child component under the wrapper, so it not possible to move the wrapper in this child component. Any other way you can suggest to solve this. Thanks

Comment: I've updated my [codesandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/file-blob-repeated-on-parent-why-bpdwy)

Comment: Another way use an array and vuex store for storing your images

Comment: @Sabjee Can u give a demo. Thanks